# ubuntu error resolving command "sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5" is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

The command "sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5" is not understand by my ubuntu terminal .It shows command not found as a output.

Comment: `strip` is in the `binutils` package, so `apt install binutils` should help

Comment: Here is a similiar page (Check out ubfan1's answer...) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir